# How to develop Clickable points within a chart which pop up a dialog box for user entry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, onclick

I have a set of large number of X & Y coordinates in a dataset to generate a graph or a chart.  Let us say that I generate a chart using this dataset. I do not have the code for the chart yet, because I do not yet know how to do what I am about to ask help for. Next, I want each of the original coordinates in the dataset, to be clickable individually, on the windows screen showing the chart. For example.. If i click a point on the chart with coordinates (x1, y1), I want a new windows screen or dialog box to open up, where I can enter some additional attributes about the x1, y1 point I just clicked, and it gets saved. Are there C# .NET libraries out there which can help me do that ? Can you please point me to some documentation or examples ? I know how to do windows programming, for UIs, event based methods, submit buttons and all that. That is not the problem. If I create a .png or a .jpg chart, it will be a static picture. I cant click inside it. So i cannot go that route.

Also, I do not have to have a chart.. anything equivalent will work too. Basically, I want to be able to generate a grid from a dataset of x, y coordinates, and then be able to click individual coordinates points on the grid, bring up a dialog box, and save the info i enter into the the dialog box for that point on the grid.

Thanks
D

Comment: Can you show some of your code or anything you have already tried?

Comment: First we have to see how you have develop the Chart. For example when you develop a bar chart, the bar is actually a kind of Rectangle which is C# graphics structure. If its a line chart, its actually polygon or collection of lines. each line has start and end points. Each start and end has x,y coordinates. When you click on a point in the line, the system will get you the distance between two end points then get you coordinates of that point by distance formula. So we don't know really yet how you developing your chart.

Comment: I do not have the code for the chart yet. I do not know if doing a chart will get me where to I want to go. Instead of a chart. something equivalent will work too. Basically, I want to be able to generate a grid from a dataset of x, y coordinates, and then be able to click individual coordinates points on the grid, bring up a dialog box, and save the info i enter into the the dialog box for that point on the grid.

Comment: Ok. So you need to create a model object with attributes x,y,info. Because the each point is unique depend on its coordinates, the click event will pass the identity of that point as parameter to the popup dialog which will be another Form in this case. Then save the info from controls in your database.

Comment: All that is fine, but the question I am facing is how do I create a chart, whose individual points, are clickable. Say if I have 3000 points ? Do i create 3000 submit buttons ? How do I lay out so many submit buttons, at the x, y coordinates of the dataset ?

Comment: Each control in c# has click event associated with them. No matter what control you define as your chart point, raise a click event. Its not wise to create 3000 buttons. I am supposing you are not using the basic chart control. But would like to create one of your own.